# Best way to store constant data in C

Tags: c, string

Let's say I'm making a C program which display information about a precious stone when the user enter the stone's name.

The stones names never change and there are less than 20 of them so reading them from a external file at runtime seems a bit overkill.

I also need to access those names from multiple files (let's say two).

What I usually do is I declare a global char * array like so:

```
char *g_rsc_names[] = {"linemate", "deraumere", "sibur", "mendiane", "phiras", "thystane"};
```

in the file I need to use those. This look pretty fine to me but this only allow me to access the names in the file where I declare this global array.

In that case, what is the best/cleanest way to store the stones names?

Comment: "The stones names never change" and "less than 20"--> Too bad, there goes multi-lingual porting and growth.  "what is the best/cleanest way to store the stones names?" --> in a file.

Comment: @chux One can determine the length of the array to change the number of elements in my solution below (`sizeof(g_rsc_names) / sizeof(*g_rsc_names)`). And by conditionally including either the stone file or the definition itself, you can get multilingual support. But, for this situation, based on OP's post, that sounds like over-engineering.

Comment: @lungj Are you certain `sizeof(g_rsc_names) / sizeof(*g_rsc_names)` will work for `char const *const g_rsc_names[]` in other files?

Comment: @lungj: you can only determine the size in the source file that defines the array; you cannot do so in any source file that references the array.  You could define a variable `size_t g_rsc_num_names = sizeof(g_rsc_names) / sizeof(g_rsc_names[0]);` in the source file, and declare it in the header `extern size_t g_rsc_num_names;` and use that.

Comment: @chux Yes. However, the `sizeof` is resolved in the compilation unit where `g_rsc_names` is initialized, so if you want the size, you'll need an extra variable that is `externed` containing the length (which will be optimized away by, e.g., `gcc`).

Comment: BTW, I interpreted "best" in this question to mean something that is as close to the original poster's code as possible. I tried to avoid adding any sort of overhead in case OP is operating in a disk space-, memory-, or compute-constrained environment. My solution below should add no overhead of any sort in the binary (unless OP hard codes stone names into other compilation units and is not running a compiler with cross-compilation unit optimizations enabled).

Comment: @lungj I'm not running in a constrained environnement, I was more looking for the "standard" way to do this (if it existed).

Comment: In that case, you might want to go with a solution that isn't below at all: create a new `struct` that defines all the attributes that you're interested in showing information about and create a map data structure to link names back to instances of the `struct`. If you want to change the attributes that are shown, you could use/write an implementation of a map-style data structure (and use that for converting stone names to `struct` pointers as well).

Comment: @TheoChampion, if you feel that any of answers solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as accepted to help future users finding the best solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap your array with a function which returns the `const char*` to the appropriate stone name and put that declaration into your global **header file** you include in multiple files:

```
const char* get_stone_name(size_t id);
```

Inside a **source file** define the `get_stone_name` like:

```
const char* get_stone_name(size_t id) {
    static const char* const names[] = {
        "linemate", "deraumere", "sibur", "mendiane", "phiras", "thystane"
    };
    return (id < (sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0])) ? names[id] : "");
}
```

Decaring `names` as `static` will guarantee that won't be initialized more than once, and as a side option you can prevent the user to index your array out of bounds.

Comment: @Akira: It wouldn't hurt to make the array constant as well. Perhaps protecting it from tampering or reducing RAM usage, depending on the target.

Comment: @Akira: I suggest you do this instead: `sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0])` to get number of elements in `names` array.

Answer (score 0):

Define an enum with symbolic names for each stone.  You would then store the enum value in the file instead of the name.

You could then define a function which will return the associated string for the given enum.

```
enum stones {
    STONE_LINEMATE,
    STONE_DERAMERE,
    ...
};

const char *stone_name(int stone)
{
    switch (stone) {
    case STONE_LINEMATE:
        return "linemate";
    case STONE_DERAMERE:
        return "deraumere";
    ...
    default:
        return "";
}
```

Comment: I found the `enum stones {
    STONE_LINEMATE,
    STONE_DERAMERE,
    ... STONE_N
};` useful to provide an `N` so other code knowns the stone type count.

Comment: Assuming the enum values start at 0 and have no gaps, you can use the enum value as an index into an array (checking the bounds to be safe) instead of using a switch.

Comment: If the gaps are not too big — so the array is not too sparse, for some ill-defined measure of 'too sparse' — then using designated initializers in the array can help: `static const char * const names[] = { [STONE_LINEMATE] = "linemate", [STONE_DERAMERE] = "deramere", … };`.  The designated initializers put the entries in the right place in the array, and leave gaps when necessary.  This assumes at least C99 support, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Put a public declaration of the stones' data type in a header file, say `stones.h`:

```
// This lets any file that includes stones.h know that you've defined 
// a variable named g_rsc_names.
extern char const *const g_rsc_names[];
```

The variable is defined as an array containing some number of character (string) pointers that will never change that each point to characters (strings) that will never change. This is to prevent programmer errors later and gives some hints to your compiler for optimization.

Then, in another file, `stones.c`:

```
// Populate the array.
char const *const g_rsc_names[] = {
    "linemate", "deraumere", "sibur", "mendiane", "phiras", "thystane" 
};
```

Now, include `stones.h` wherever you want to reference the array. Make sure to compile the `stones.c` file and link it to your binary.

Comment: How does code use the array and not run off it end?  `stones.h` would benefit with a count or `g_rsc_names[]` needs a sentinel.

Comment: `sizeof(g_rsc_names) / sizeof(*g_rsc_names)`

Comment: You can't use `sizeof` in this case because `g_rsc_names` is incomplete: `invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘const char * const[]’`

Comment: Externed constant for size? I.e., calculate the size in the `stones.c` compilation unit and then `extern` it in the `.h` file.